# MySQL Database Sync

Tags: php, mysql, import

I have 2 MySQL databases with similar data. The difference is that one has an email column with about 2000 entries and the other has an email column with no entries. Is there some sort of bulk operation that could be done to copy the 2000 email addresses from database 1 to database 2?

I'm looking for a way to do this with PHP, or better yet, an all-inclusive query to run via phpMyAdmin.

Comment: If it's identical data, why not just copying this table?

Comment: @Sven Your last name wouldn't be Loth would it?

Comment: @Sven They are similar tables - not identical. I worded that wrong in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
UPDATE db1.tbl a SET a.email = b.email
JOIN db2.tbl b ON b.id = a.id
```

Comment: Not extremely familiar with SQL statements - would need more clarity.

Comment: As long as both databases are on the same server and have the same user privileges, then you can query off both databases using a single query. This query will update `db1`'s table with `db2`'s e-mails based on the `id`.

Comment: Almost got it...when I run the query, I get a syntax error for the JOIN statement.

Comment: @user1710563 Put it in a fiddle.